# ARKit Reset Session Memory Leak

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, memory-leaks, arkit

I've been working with ARKit recently while doing some memory leak profiling and noticed that when resetting (calling `.run` again) the ARSession using the `.resetTracking` option, there is a memory leak that the Leaks tool reports as coming from somewhere to do with `vImageMapping_CreateFromMap_Image8U`. I'm not sure if it is something that I'm doing incorrectly or if it an issue on ARKit's side.

Here is a simple code snippet of the SceneKit ViewController setup (modified from an Apple sample):

```
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session.delegate = self
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked() {
        resetTracking()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        resetTracking()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        session.pause()
    }

    func resetTracking() {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        }
        session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking]) 
    }
```

To recreate,

1. Start the app (can snapshot a memory profile here to see there are no leaks),
2. hit the "reset" button we've created,
3. generate a memory profile

In the profile, there is an indication that there is a 409600 byte-malloc block that has leaked for every reset. [Image of the leak in the profiling tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQmES.png)